# syntax error with .format() (Python 3.2.3)

Tags: python

So I am trying to write a program that writes a word, fills 20 spaces with markup(< or >), then writes that same word backwards. It also takes user input.
Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong

```
 while test2 == 1 : 
    test = input("Enter a word to format. Entering QUIT will exit the program:")
    if test == ("quit"):
        print("You have quit the program.")
        break
    else:
        print("{0:*<20}{1:*>20})".format(
            "test")(["test"::-1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically you have a `"` in the wrong place in your last `print` statement.

```
print("{0:*<20}{1:*>20}").format("test")(["test"::-1])
                       ^
```

You also some other syntax errors with your `format()` arguments, this will work for the literal string "test" but you'll need to replace it with a variable to use it with actual user input:

```
print("{0:*<20}{1:*>20}").format("test","test"[::-1])
```

Comment: That wouldn't help. The entire statement is broken.

Comment: Hi Dan, can you suggest some changes to allow me to print something like monkey>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>yeknom

Comment: `">"*5` will give you `">>>>>"`, in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line has errors, try the follwing to get 20 spaces between the words

```
In [1]: s = "test"
In [2]: print('{0:<20}{1}'.format(s,s[::-1]))

test                tset
```

You can also use `print('{0}{1}{2}'.format(s," "*20,s[::-1]))` which is subjectively cleaner.